# Why none direcotry send via pipe to a grep get searched result?

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

My current directory:

```
pwd
/home/debian
```

Search a string `-dig` in `/home/debian/mydoc/source`.

```
grep -lr -e "-dig" /home/debian/mydoc/source  
#get nothing as output
```

In my opinion ,sent nothing via pipe  to next grep will get nothing too.

```
grep -lr -e "-dig" /home/debian/mydoc/source | xargs -d '\n' grep -lr -e "dns"
#my desired output:nothing ,none directory send to xargs
```

Check it :

```
grep -lr -e "-dig" /home/debian/mydoc/source | xargs -d '\n' grep -lr -e "dns"
/home/debian/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/b2b96208dbb4fdff_0
/home/debian/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/33f7b9aaf4e3cb37_0
/home/debian/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/b7b3cae8052a94ea_0
```

The real searched result is not as my expected,it is the same as `grep -lr -e "dns" /home/debian`.

```
grep -lr -e "dns" /home/debian
/home/debian/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/b2b96208dbb4fdff_0
/home/debian/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/33f7b9aaf4e3cb37_0
/home/debian/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/b7b3cae8052a94ea_0
```

Please tell me the principle behind the bash command--`grep -lr -e "-dig" /home/debian/mydoc/source | xargs -d '\n' grep -lr -e "dns"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first rep certainly returns nothing, so the second grep gets an empty args list from xargs.

The second grep includes -r (recursive).

From the man grep page:

> -r, --recursive ::
>          Note  that  if  no  file operand  is  given,  grep  searches  the  working directory.

So the grep run by xargs reverts to /home/debian.